# When saving with the Wayback Machine, claims "The client does not have access rights" HTTP status=403

Tags: wordpress, 403-forbidden

I have a WordPress installation which the Wayback Machine can no longer archive.  I'm posting this here because I intuit this is a lower level problem.

When visiting

https://web.archive.org/save/blog.spiralofhope.com

I get

```
The client does not have access rights to http://blog.spiralofhope.com/ (HTTP status=403).
```

When this problem arose, I had not made any changes at all:  WordPress, plugins, etc.  I don't have control over the server side of things.

I explored:

- Reinstalling WordPress

  - I am using 6.0
- Disabling all plugins
- renaming my `.htaccess`
- server logs via ssh (doesn't have anything appear when I attempt to archive)
- server logs via my control panel (it's opaque and I'm not sure how to search for anything)

I've done web searches on multiple engines for phrases like `The client does not have access rights`, with the status, etc. with regards to the Wayback Machine.  There (terrible) forum didn't give anything related.  I haven't been able to find another user with a similar problem.

[I posted to ask for help](https://archive.org/post/1124865/http-status403-the-client-does-not-have-access-rights) but none has arrived so far.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a mixture of the Blackhole for Bad Bots plugin and a cooldown in the Wayback Machine.

The plugin was aggressively blocking their bot. When blocked, the bot would no longer work for that URL. So even if the plugin was disabled the bot would still not work.

The resolution was to disable the plugin, wait for a day or so, then re-try the URLs.

Simple solution, complex troubleshooting!